# Error serializing with getStaticProps - nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js

This is my getTopGifts function:

```
export async function getTopGifts() {
const data = [{"id":1,"title":"test"}]

return data
}
```

but when I use above function on got error:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  // fetch list of gifts
  const gifts = getTopGifts()
  console.log(typeof(_gifts))
  return {
    props: {
      gifts: gifts
    },
  }
}
```

my error:

```
Error: Error serializing `.gifts` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/gifts".
Reason: `object` ("[object Promise]") cannot be serialized as JSON. Please only return JSON serializable data types.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made `getTopGifts` an `async` function, try using `await` to resolve the value of `getTopGifts`. Without `await` it is a pending promise:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  // fetch list of gifts
  const gifts = await getTopGifts()
  console.log(typeof(gifts));
  return {
    props: {
      gifts,
    },
  }
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: i got caught on exactly this for ages...was trying to fix the called function returning a Promise but really it was just because  getStaticProps() didnt have 'await' when calling it... so it wasn't...waiting :)